# Finding cutoff points for ordinal multi-class situation

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, scipy

Now I have a table data with 50,000 rows (eg representing distinct users) and two columns: one is for a label of classes 'A' to 'E', and the other is for a score with decimal points like 0.0 to 14,000,000.00. 
My task is to attach a new label to the users to either of 'A' to 'E' based on the the score on the second column.

Here, I want to minimize the change of old label (the first column) to new label as much as possible.

Class 'A' - 'E' are regarded as ordinal, so I started with assigning the 'loss' for the change per user: like A -> B is loss=1.0, A -> C is loss=2.0, etc., and tried some scipy minimize function on Python to minimize the total loss for the entire users to find the four best cutoff points for A<>B, B<>C, C<>D, D<>E, but did not work well (never changed from the initial point I gave.), which is not surprising because the loss function is a step function and has zero gradient almost everywhere.

Here's what I ran for your reference. obj3 is a function to calculate the total loss with input of a list with four elements representing the cutoff points for D<>E, C<>D, B<>C, A<>B in this order. Since the cutoff point of D<>E is always smaller than the one of C<>D and so forth, I used three constraints:

```
b = (0,max(df['score']))
bounds = (b,b,b,b)

constraints = [
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1] - x[0]},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[2] - x[1]},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[3] - x[2]},
]

sol = minimize(obj3, thres_init, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints) 
sol.x
```

The old label and new label can have some shuffles (like by descending score order, the old label is like 'AABDEAABD...', the one-time brute force approach may not necessarily work well I suppose (did not try yet.)

Using the index of sorted unique score list (there are 5,000 unique scores), I also thought of some metaheuristic approach such as GA (because now we have smaller search space but it's combinatorial optimization) but I am not sure if it's worth investing my time.

Does anyone have an idea of the algorithm to solve this optimization problem??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the class `A->E` valued as `0->5`.

Let `Y` be the array score sorted by increasing order

eg:  `Y = [1,2,5,...,14*1e6]`

Let `X` be the associated valued class before assignment

eg:  `X = [0,5,2,3,...1]`

Assuming we thus want `4` cuts at position `c_i`, `i = 0 to 3`, `c_j > c_i if j > i`,

The cost of a given combination of `c_i` is `sum_i( |X[0:c_i] - i| )`

We could write the very dumb minimzation function (**not** valid python)

```
#the cost of a class starting from start to end
def cost(start, end, label):
    return sum(abs(X[old: end] - label]))

# old is the starting index
# n is the number of cuts we still have to place
def rec(old, n):
    if n == 0:
        # we can't place more cuts, so it is our final class
        # the cost is the diff for that class "move"
        return cost(old, len(X), n)

    min_cost = Infinity
    # we check every position possible for our next cut
    # note that I am very likely not to be idx accurate
    for c_i in range(old, len(X)):
        rec_cost = rec(c_i+1, n-1)
        current_class_cost = cost(old, c_i+1, n)
        total_cost = rec_cost + current_class_cost

        # we update the min_cost on a better found solution
        # we can trivially backtrack the all the c_i's position as well
        min_cost = min(min_cost, total_cost)

    return total_cost
```

The associated dynamic approach be like

```
take the first cut as label_0
for all positions
    generate the associated cost of that cut for that position. 
    (you could reuse the cost of the previous calculated position, but it is not the point)

take the next cut (as label_1), for all generated (previous) positions as p, 
    for all positions as new_position > p
        put the new_position's cost as min(new_position's cost, p + cost from p to that new_position)

do so until first cut is placed
At that stage, you must for every position add the remaining class cost
```

space complexity: O(n_scores)
time complexity: O(n_cuts * n_scores * n_scores)

Below *seems* to work, but not really tested either. So be cautious...

```
X=[0,0,1,1,0,1 ,1, 2, 2, 2 ,1]
Y=[1,2,5,7,8,10,11,11,11,11,12] #just useless

def cost(left, right, label):
    s = 0
    for i in range(left, right+1):
        s += abs(X[i]-label)
    return s

def dp():
    n_scores = len(X)
    positions = [0]*n_scores
    for pos in range(n_scores):
        positions[pos] = {'cost':cost(0, pos, 0), 'cuts':[pos]}

    for label_cut in range(1, max(X)):

        next_positions = [{ 'cost':1e5, 'cuts':[]} for i in range(n_scores)]

        for pos in range(n_scores):
            p = positions[pos]
            for cut in range(pos+1, n_scores-1):
                c = cost(pos+1, cut, label_cut)
                total_cost = c + p['cost']
                next_p = next_positions[cut]
                if total_cost < next_p['cost']:
                    next_positions[cut] = {'cost': total_cost, 'cuts': p['cuts'] + [cut] }
        positions = next_positions

    #print the position for which the cost is minimal
    best = {'cost':1e5}
    for pos in range(n_scores):
        p = positions[pos]
        total_cost = p['cost'] + cost(pos+1, n_scores-1, max(X))
        if total_cost < best['cost']:
            best = {
                'cuts': p['cuts'],
                'cost': total_cost
            }
    return best
```